# Using getActualTypeArguments in a generic context

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection

There are other related questions e.g. [6624113](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624113/get-type-name-for-generic-parameter-of-generic-class), [3403909](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime), [4516891](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516891/how-to-get-the-actual-type-arguments-to-an-indirectly-implemented-generic-interf) but my question is simpler and more specific.

I want to know at runtime what type my class was parameterized with - I want a Class object of the type of the type parameter.  Because of type erasure, the expression `T.class` doesn't work, and there is no function like `typeof(T)` in C# to get it.

However, there is some "uber-reflection" available via [ParameterizedType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) and related classes, which gets me almost all of the way there.

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public class MyClass<T> {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new MyClass<Integer>().printTypeParam();
    }

    public void printTypeParam() {
        class DummyT extends MyClass<T> {}
        class DummyString extends MyClass<String> {}

        ParameterizedType ptT =
            ((ParameterizedType) DummyT.class.getGenericSuperclass() );

        ParameterizedType ptString =
            ((ParameterizedType) DummyString.class.getGenericSuperclass() );

        System.out.println( "DummyT: " + ptT + " " + ptT.getActualTypeArguments()[0] );
        System.out.println( "DummyString: " + ptString + " " + ptString.getActualTypeArguments()[0] );

    }
}
```

When I run the above I see this output:

```
DummyT: MyClass<T> T
DummyString: MyClass<java.lang.String> class java.lang.String
```

As you can see, this works for when the type arguments are known at compile-time at the line of code containing the call to `getGenericSuperClass`, but where that call is itself dealing with generics it simply prints the name of the type parameter.

Is there any way I can get the first line to print `java.lang.Integer` instead of `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, plain and simple.  `Integer` is not reified, it is completely [erased](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  If you don't believe me, compile the file once with `Integer` and once with `Long`.  The two binary class files will be absolutely identical.

Type erasure is a harsh reality that you won't be able to get around.  I suggest you rethink why you *need* it instead of going down the path of introducing hacks to try to *avoid* it.

Useful AngelikaLanger Generics FAQ topics:

- [What is type erasure?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20erasure?)
- [What is reification?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20reification?)
- [What is a reifiable type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ106)

Comment: I actually did what you suggested, and you will be unsurprised to hear you are right: 2 files are created: MyClass$1DummyString.class  MyClass$1DummyT.class  MyClass.class and they are binary-identical if I change the type on line 5 to Long instead of Integer.

Comment: I am happily using the workaround/pattern of passing a class instance to the constructor - I was just curious on whether the less-verbose solution was possible.